# Capabilities require entitlements from plist may not function Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, warnings

I'm getting *Dependency Analysis Warning : Capabilities that require entitlements from "Fit/entitlements.plist" may not function in the Simulator because Ad Hoc code signing is not allowed for the SDK: iOS 8.1*

I have downloaded source code and using Xcode 6.1 / iPhone 6 simulator.
How to fix this warning?

[image: Screenshot for warning]

Comment: What entitlements are you requesting?

Answer (score 2):

It's not something you can "fix".  It's informational.  The simulator does not support codesigned entitlements and does not have some functionality that is gated by such entitlements on device.

Comment: So to be explicit, does this mean it's impossible to test the iOS 8 document picker on the Simulator?

Comment: Answering my own question: you CAN test the iOS 8 doc picker in the simulator, but only if you have the Xcode-managed app-specific provisioning profile installed.  Otherwise the entitlements don't get embedded in the app.